# parent().filter(":first") doesn't work

Tags: jquery

I have:

```
<td>firstTD</td>
<td>secondTD</td>
<td>thirdTD</td>
<td>
      <img src="img/cross.png" onclick="alert($(this).parent().parent().filter('td:first').val());">
</td>
```

Why I didn't get an alert: "firstTD" ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try

```
alert($(this).parent().parent().children().filter('td:first').text());
```

or you can use

```
$(this).parent().parent().children().first().text()
```

Comment: I was mean text(), not val(). Children() is my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
alert($(this).parent().parent().children('td:first').text());
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kTkK4/

Options for getting the first element:

`:first-child`: http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/
`:first`: http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/
`.first()`: http://api.jquery.com/first/

You shouldn't use `.val()` for non-input elements, instead use the `.text()` function.

> The .val() method is primarily used to get the values of form elements
>   such as input, select and textarea.

Answer (score 0):

Because you can't have `td` elements without `table`, `tbody`, and `tr` elements. Also, `.filter()` filters an array of matched elements, as suggested in other answers, place the selector in a `.children()` call.